# Long formula works when put in cell but not when inserted from VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Firstly, this is a long and ugly formula warning.

What I am trying to do is to get VBA to insert this formula into Excel. If I get VBA to insert it without the '=' and then manually add it in Excel, it proves the formula works. Yet if I try to get VBA to insert and run the formula, with the '=' prefix, all in one go then I get a run-time error.

Any ideas how I can get VBA to insert and run this formula?

```
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
"=IF(P1=""EQS FW"",IF(Statistics!B3=""Cadmium"",IF(AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(INDEX($B$3:$B$300,MATCH(""Alkalinity as CaCO3"",$B$3:$B$300,0))),9))>'Hardness-bands'!$B$5,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(INDEX($B$3:$B$300,MATCH(""Alkalinity as CaCO3"",$B$3:$B$300,0))),9))<'Hardness-bands'!$C$5),'Hardness-bands'!$D$5,IF(AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(INDEX($B$3:$B$300,MATCH(""Alkalinity as CaCO3"",$B$3:$B$300,0))),9))>'Hardness-bands'!$B$6,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(INDEX($B$3:$B$300,MATCH(""Alkalinity as CaCO3"",$B$3:$B$300,0))),9))<'Hardness-bands'!$C$6),'Hardness-bands'!$D$6,IF(AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(INDEX($B$3:$B$300,MATCH(""Alkalinity as CaCO3"",$B$3:$B$300,0))),9))>'Hardness-bands'!$B$7,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(INDEX($B$3:$B$300,MATCH(""Alkalinity as CaCO3"",$B$3:$B$300,0))),9))<'Hardness-bands'!$C$7),'Hardness-bands'!$D$7,IF(AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(INDEX($B$3:$B$300,MATCH(""Alkalinity as CaCO3"",$B$3:$B$300,0))),9))>'Hardness-bands'!$B$8,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(INDEX($B$3:$B$300,MATCH(""Alkalinity as CaCO3"",$B$3:$B$300,0))),9))" & _
"<'Hardness-bands'!$C$8),'Hardness-bands'!$D$8,IF(AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(INDEX($B$3:$B$300,MATCH(""Alkalinity as CaCO3"",$B$3:$B$300,0))),9))>'Hardness-bands'!$B$9,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(INDEX($B$3:$B$300,MATCH(""Alkalinity as CaCO3"",$B$3:$B$300,0))),9))<'Hardness-bands'!$C$9),'Hardness-bands'!$D$9,""Err""))))),IF(Statistics!B4=""Copper"",IF(AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(INDEX($B$3:$B$300,MATCH(""Alkalinity as CaCO3"",$B$3:$B$300,0))),9))>'Hardness-bands'!$B$13,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(INDEX($B$3:$B$300,MATCH(""Alkalinity as CaCO3"",$B$3:$B$300,0))),9))<'Hardness-bands'!$C$13),'Hardness-bands'!$D$13,IF(AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(INDEX($B$3:$B$300,MATCH(""Alkalinity as CaCO3"",$B$3:$B$300,0))),9))>'Hardness-bands'!$B$14,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(INDEX($B$3:$B$300,MATCH(""Alkalinity as CaCO3"",$B$3:$B$300,0))),9))<'Hardness-bands'!$C$14),'Hardness-bands'!$D$14,IF(AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(INDEX($B$3:$B$300,MATCH(""Alkalinity as CaCO3"",$B$3:$B$300,0))),9))>'Hardness-bands'!$B$15,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(INDEX($B$3:$B$300," & _
"MATCH(""Alkalinity as CaCO3"",$B$3:$B$300,0))),9))<'Hardness-bands'!$C$15),'Hardness-bands'!$D$15,IF(AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(INDEX($B$3:$B$300,MATCH(""Alkalinity as CaCO3"",$B$3:$B$300,0))),9))>'Hardness-bands'!$B$16,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(INDEX($B$3:$B$300,MATCH(""Alkalinity as CaCO3"",$B$3:$B$300,0))),9))<'Hardness-bands'!$C$16),'Hardness-bands'!$D$16,""Err"")))),IF(Statistics!B4=""Zinc"",IF(AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(INDEX($B$3:$B$300,MATCH(""Alkalinity as CaCO3"",$B$3:$B$300,0))),9))>'Hardness-bands'!$B$20,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(INDEX($B$3:$B$300,MATCH(""Alkalinity as CaCO3"",$B$3:$B$300,0))),9))<'Hardness-bands'!$C$20),'Hardness-bands'!$D$20,IF(AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(INDEX($B$3:$B$300,MATCH(""Alkalinity as CaCO3"",$B$3:$B$300,0))),9))>'Hardness-bands'!$B$21,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(INDEX($B$3:$B$300,MATCH(""Alkalinity as CaCO3"",$B$3:$B$300,0))),9))<'Hardness-bands'!$C$21),'Hardness-bands'!$D$21,IF(AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(INDEX($B$3:$B$300,MATCH(""Alkalinity as CaCO3"",$B$3:$B$300,0))),9))>'Hardness-ban" & _
"ds'!$B$22,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(INDEX($B$3:$B$300,MATCH(""Alkalinity as CaCO3"",$B$3:$B$300,0))),9))<'Hardness-bands'!$C$22),'Hardness-bands'!$D$22,IF(AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(INDEX($B$3:$B$300,MATCH(""Alkalinity as CaCO3"",$B$3:$B$300,0))),9))>'Hardness-bands'!$B$23,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(INDEX($B$3:$B$300,MATCH(""Alkalinity as CaCO3"",$B$3:$B$300,0))),9))<'Hardness-bands'!$C$23),'Hardness-bands'!$D$23,""Err"")))),Statistics!R4))),Statistics!R3)"
```

Comment: It turns out the issue was related to 'ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1' - because of course my formula was not entered in R1C1 notation!

Answer (score 0):

Wow, that is pretty big.  You definitely ought to break that up a fair amount.

Anyway, I think it might be because you are trying to insert speech marks into your string.  In VBA debug mode, copy the entire string and have a look at it in the immediate window.  Is it exactly the same as the string when in an Excel cell?  My guess would be not.

Try replacing the double speech marks:
P1=""EQS FW""

with something like this:
P1=" & """" & "EQS FW" & """"

That will insert the speech marks correctly for you.

Another thought.  It will be tricky doing the speech mark adjustments, so start by trying it out on a small section of the vast formula and build it up gradually.